# Calling componentDidUpdate on specific changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a react class component and a table that shows a list of cars. It uses componentDidUpdate to get the list again when updating. It looks like this :

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.getCars()
}
```

getCars looks like this :

```
 getCars() {
   APIService.getCars().then((response) => {
        this.setState({ cars: response.data })
    })
}
```

The problem is that when I want to sort the table, the componentDidUpdate is called and the list sorts then goes back to the regular state.

This is how the sorting looks :

```
 onSort(event, sortKey){
        if(sortKey=='carId' || sortKey=='dailyPrice') {
        const cars = this.state.cars;
        cars.sort((a,b) => a[sortKey]-b[sortKey])
        this.setState({cars})
        } else {
        const cars = this.state.cars;
        cars.sort((a,b) => a[sortKey].localeCompare(b[sortKey]))
        this.setState({cars})
      }
    }
```

I tried using this.getCars() on another function, like after adding a car :

```
addCar() {
    let addCarNameField = document.getElementById("addCarNameField").value;
    let addCarModelField = document.getElementById("addCarModelField").value.toUpperCase();
    let addCarDailyPriceField = document.getElementById("addCarDailyPriceField").value;
    
    let size = '-SIZE'



    if(addCarModelField == 'SMALL' || addCarModelField == 'MID' || addCarModelField == 'BIG' ) {
        APIService.addCar(addCarNameField,addCarModelField+size,addCarDailyPriceField);
        this.getCars()
    }else {
    alert("Invalid model, write small, mid or big!")
}
}
```

But I get this TypeError : `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getCars')`

How can I make componentDidUpdate to not be called only when onSort is called? or is there a better way to update the list instead of calling this.getCars?

***Edit*** : I solved this by binding this.getCars in the constructor :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { cars: [] }
    this.onSort = this.onSort.bind(this)
    this.getCars = this.getCars.bind(this);
}
```

And making the function that is calling getCars an arrow function :

```
addCar = () => {
    let addCarNameField = document.getElementById("addCarNameField").value;
    let addCarModelField = document.getElementById("addCarModelField").value.toUpperCase();
    let addCarDailyPriceField = document.getElementById("addCarDailyPriceField").value;

    let size = '-SIZE'
    let clicked = false;


    if (addCarModelField == 'SMALL' || addCarModelField == 'MID' || addCarModelField == 'BIG') {
        APIService.addCar(addCarNameField, addCarModelField + size, addCarDailyPriceField);
        this.getCars()
    } else {
        alert("Invalid model, write small, mid or big!")
    }  
}
```

And for some reason, calling getCars once doesn't work, but twice re-renders, so I changed getCars to use the APIService twice :

```
 APIService.getCars().then((response) => {
        this.setState({ cars: response.data })
    })

    APIService.getCars().then((response) => {
        this.setState({ cars: response.data })
    })
}
```

Comment: this.setState({ cars: response.data }) i think this sentence is  making you a problem ,because when you using a UseState it is calling first to the use state and in the first time you dont have any value because of that you got an eror undefind.

Comment: How would I rewrite it to make it work?

Comment: i was looking here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate    "You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition"  this sequnce from that website

Comment: Is setState not being called already when I am using this.getCars inside componentDidUpdate?

Comment: Yes ,its called but ,because of that in first time when it called you got a eror

Comment: I edited my post with my solution

Comment: I'm glad I was able to guide you :)